# Java - Newline and forward slash delimiter

Tags: java, regex

```
        mykeyboard.useDelimiter("[/\n]");
```

Is what I'm using for a delimiter. I am trying to input dates in the format of mm/dd/yyyy. However, the delimiter for new line will not work. For instance 11/12/1900 and hitting enter gives me this error:

```
 Exception in thread "main" java.util.InputMismatchException
at java.util.Scanner.throwFor(Unknown Source)
at java.util.Scanner.next(Unknown Source)
at java.util.Scanner.nextInt(Unknown Source)
at java.util.Scanner.nextInt(Unknown Source)
```

Only when I input 11/12/1900/ does it actually work.

Answer (score 1):

Try this instead:

```
mykeyboard.useDelimiter("[/\r\n]");
```

The enter key on a keyboard is actually a carriage return (\r) not a newline; plus there could be some line ending translations on input depending on the terminal / platform.

Comment: Oh, it actually worked! Thanks! I've been searching for the past hour and I could not figure out why \n wasn't working.

Comment: @SotiriosDelimanolis that only works if you're parsing text from the same system.  (which might be the case)

Comment: @JohnGardner Right, given `mykeyboard`.

Answer (score 0):

i think you can just seprate it by the slash "/"
try this:
string date = keyboard.netxLine()
date.split("/")